# Ignoring Compose function naming error in Spotless(ktlint)

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, ktlint, spotless

I just added Spotless to my project with this config:

**build.gradle.kts(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.diffplug.spotless") version "6.23.3"
}
...
spotless {
    kotlin {
        target("**/*.kt", "**/*.kts")
        ktlint()
        targetExclude("${layout.buildDirectory}/**/*.kt", "bin/**/*.kt", "buildSrc/**/*.kt")
    }
}
```

however, after running `./gradlew spotlessApply` in terminal it gonna throw this error:

```
Error on line: 20, column: 5
rule: standard:function-naming
Function name should start with a lowercase letter (except factory methods) and use camel case
```

But in Line 20 I have a composable fun which should not start with a lowercase letter:

```
@Composable
fun ExplorerScreen() {
 ...
}
```

how can I ignore this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ktlint_function_naming_ignore_when_annotated_with=Composable` to .editorconfig

Check out [this PR](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/pull/1094/files) from the nowinandroid repo

Comment: Feature was added to ktlint here: https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/2259#issuecomment-1732333419